# junitで、1つのクラスに2つの@Testのアノテーションをつけたメソッドを書くとNoSuchElementExceptionが出る。

Tags: java, junit, exception

今、しりとりのゲームを作ろうと思い、Javaでプログラミングしています。

Junitに以下のようなテストケースを書いたところ、NoSuchElementExceptionが出てしまいます。

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class IOProcessorTest {
    @Test
    public void testPromptInput() {
        String input = "シリトリ 1 しりとり 2 シリトリ 1 シリトリ f 1";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
    }
    @Test
    public void testConvertToKata() {
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.convertToKata("しりとり"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.convertToKata("シリトリ"));
    }   
}
```

テストしているクラスのコードは以下の通りです。

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class IOProcessor {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static FormChecker form = new FormChecker();
    static AnsChecker ans = new AnsChecker();

    public static String promptInput(String msg) {
        boolean confirmed = false;
        String word = null;
        while (!confirmed) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            word = sc.next();
            confirmed = confirmInput(word);
        }
        return word;
    }

    private static boolean confirmInput(String word) {
        boolean confirmed = true;
        boolean validInput = false;
        while (!validInput) {
            System.out.println("What you hava entered is " + word + ".");
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            System.out.println("1. Yes, I want to continue. 2. No, I want to change.");
            String input = sc.next();

            switch (input) {
                case "1":
                    validInput = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    confirmed = false;
                    validInput = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2.");
            }
        }
        return confirmed;
    }

    public static String convertToKata(String word) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(word);
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            char c = sb.charAt(i);
            if (c >= 'ぁ' && c <= 'ん') {
                sb.setCharAt(i, (char) (c - 'ぁ' + 'ァ'));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

今、テストに2つメソッドがありますが、testConvertToKataだけをコメントアウトしてから実行すると、例外が出ません。逆に、testPromptInputだけをコメントアウトしてから実行した場合も例外が出ません。2つのメソッドを同時に実行した場合にのみ例外が出るのですがどうしてでしょうか。

プログラミング初心者で、初めてstackoverflowで質問するので分かりにくい点があるかと思いますが、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 問題なく動く場合:

1. System.in を `System.setIn` によって、`シリトリ 1 しりとり 2 シリトリ 1 シリトリ f 1` の ByteArrayInputStream に設定する
2. `static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` が実行される
3. `promptInput` が呼ばれる

#### 問題が発生している場合:

1. `static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)` が実行される(プロセスの標準入力に対するスキャナが定義される)
2. System.in を `System.setIn` によって、`シリトリ 1 しりとり 2 シリトリ 1 シリトリ f 1` の ByteArrayInputStream に設定する
3. `promptInput` が呼ばれる -> スキャナが見ている InputStream は変わらず、標準入力から読み込もうとする

#### 確認方法:

`promptInput` が最初に `Scanner#next` を呼ぶ直前にブレークポイント仕込んでデバッグ実行、 sc.source.lock のオブジェクトのクラスが異なる

#### 原因:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9130560/3090068

上記によれば、 static ブロックの初期化コードは、「そのクラスが実際に使われる直前まで行われない可能性がある」。

- 問題なく動いている場合は、 `IOProcessor.promptInput` が最初に呼ばれて、そこで static の初期化コードが走った場合。
- 問題が発生しているのは、 `IOProcessor.convertToKana` が最初に呼ばれて、そこで static の初期化コードが走り、そののちに System.setIn している。

だと考えられます。

#### 対処方法:

promptInput メソッドを、 static メソッドではなく、普通のメソッドとして取り扱い、 `IOProcessor` はフィールドに InputStream をとるようにする。 promptInput はこのメンバー InputStream から入力を読み込む。

### 対処したコード

以下のようになると思います。

#### IOProcessor

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class IOProcessor {

    private final Scanner sc;
//    static FormChecker form = new FormChecker();
//    static AnsChecker ans = new AnsChecker();

    public IOProcessor(InputStream in) {
        sc = new Scanner(in);
    }

    public String promptInput(String msg) {
        boolean confirmed = false;
        String word = null;
        while (!confirmed) {
            System.out.println(msg);
            word = sc.next();
            confirmed = confirmInput(word);
        }
        return word;
    }

    private boolean confirmInput(String word) {
        boolean confirmed = true;
        boolean validInput = false;
        while (!validInput) {
            System.out.println("What you hava entered is " + word + ".");
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            System.out.println("1. Yes, I want to continue. 2. No, I want to change.");
            String input = sc.next();

            switch (input) {
                case "1":
                    validInput = true;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    confirmed = false;
                    validInput = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter 1 or 2.");
            }
        }
        return confirmed;
    }

    public static String convertToKata(String word) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(word);
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
            char c = sb.charAt(i);
            if (c >= 'ぁ' && c <= 'ん') {
                sb.setCharAt(i, (char) (c - 'ぁ' + 'ァ'));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

#### IOProcessorTest

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class IOProcessorTest {
    @Test
    public void testPromptInput() {
        String input = "シリトリ 1 しりとり 2 シリトリ 1 シリトリ f 1";
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
        IOProcessor ioProcessor = new IOProcessor(in);
        assertEquals("シリトリ", ioProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", ioProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", ioProcessor.promptInput("テストします。"));
    }
    @Test
    public void testConvertToKata() {
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.convertToKata("しりとり"));
        assertEquals("シリトリ", IOProcessor.convertToKata("シリトリ"));
    }
}
```

Comment: @MasatoNagashima コメントの途中で Enter を押してしまったのだと理解 :)

Comment: Inoueさん

申し訳ございません、その通りです。

キーボードから読み込んでいる入力を、文字列(シリトリ 1 しりとり 2 シリトリ 1 シリトリ f 1)から読み込むように変える、その変更のタイミングで問題が発生するかどうかが変わるということでしょうか。

また、その変更が必ずScanner クラスのnewより前になるようにするために、テストコードのほうではなく、IOProcessorのほうを変えるということでしょうか。

Comment: @MasatoNagashima その理解であっています。 System.in を変える処理、というのは、例えばシェルを実装しているであるとか、そういったプロセス自体の挙動をいじる場面以外では、設計としてあまり正しくないような気がします。 (ありとあらゆる、その他ライブラリは、 System.in は不変であることを前提に書かれていると思われますので。。） なので、 IOProcessor の方を変更する法がベターであるという認識です。

Comment: さん
---promptInput メソッドを、 static メソッドではなく、普通のメソッドとして取り扱い、 
というところは分かるのですが

---IOProcessor はフィールドに InputStream をとるようにする。
というのは、フィールドにInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream (sc.next().getBytes());となるのでしょうか?

また、
---promptInput はこのメンバー InputStream から入力を読み込む。
というのは、System.setIn (in);を書いてから、残りの処理を書くという形になるのでしょうか。

ご丁寧にお答えいただいているところに重ねて質問をしてしまい心苦しいのですが、お答えいただければ非常に助かります。

Comment: @MasatoNagashima 私の意図している修正方法を、回答に追記いたしました。

Comment: Inoue返事が遅れ、申し訳ございません。解決できました。ご回答いただき、本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: @MasatoNagashima お役に立てたようで何よりです。本回答投稿で問題が解決した場合には、この回答を承認いただけますでしょうか？システム的に、本質問が解決済みであることを示すことができます。参考:  https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers